# How to add Alpha -channels en masse with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, alpha-transparency

Suppose a dir with a lot of images, some of them miss the alpha-channel so looking bad against a background. I thought every picture had alpha -channel but some pictures now show white instead of having transparency. How can I add the alpha channels en masse?

**Not Working**

> $ convert imageNoAlpha.png -alpha on imageAlpha.png

Comment: ...suppose I am on my server without X and I notice this missing alpha-channel. I pretty much must go back to my desktop that is time-consuming and do small edits with Gimp -- wish I could do this with ImageMagick directly on commandline -- I need to somehow specify: replace all white with alpha-channel i.e. transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will change white to transparent as in you coment BUT any other white in the image will be transparent as well:

```
convert input.jpg -background none -transparent white -flatten output.png
```

Comment: Thank you! +1 One last thought: could you add white-threshold so also colors close to white are made transparent? Yes apparently like this `"convert input.jpg -white-threshold 88% -background none -transparent white -flatten output.png"`?

Comment: You use -fuzz: convert input.jpg -background none -fuzz 12% -transparent white -flatten output.png

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bonzo, I was able to get very cool results even without anti-alias! You can see the difference in the eyes with the below picture. I don't know how much you lose information by this but at least I am more able to adjust things, not so easy in anti-aliasing at least for me.

[image]

```
$ convert in.png -background none -fuzz 10% -transparent white -flatten out.png
```

En masse -approach is probably easiest with a bash -for-loop or use ImageMagick -pkg built for python. I don't know which approach is better, I will leave this here for future answers to improve. Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure of over-thinking: did Zsh have the feature `$ someFunc in[1..10].png out[1..10].png`? I think it did but cannot remember the syntax, thinking...